# Python 3.4 ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1638)

Tags: python-3.x, ssl

I've the project to connect a distant vim (on my server) to my client with PIPE of the subprocess stdin, stdout through a SSL socket. I use Python 3.4.
My socket (cSock in the code) is SSL wrapped and i've the same error each time I try to open Vim. Here my code:

```
vimProc = sp.Popen(["rvim", file], bufsize=0, stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE)

cSock.settimeout(1)

rec = Reception(cSock, vimProc)
emi = Emission(cSock, vimProc)

rec.start()
emi.start()

rec.join()
emi.join()
```

And here my threads of Reception and Emission

```
class Reception(threading.Thread):

def __init__(self, sock, proc):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.sock = sock
    self.proc = proc

def run(self):
    while self.proc.poll() == None:
        try:
            self.proc.communicate(self.sock.recv(1))
        except socket.timeout:
            pass


class Emission(threading.Thread):

def __init__(self, sock, proc):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.sock = sock
    self.proc = proc

def run(self):
    while self.proc.poll() == None:
        try:
            outs = self.proc.stdout.read(1)
            if outs == "":
                print("EOF reached")
            else:
                self.sock.send(outs)

        except socket.timeout: 
            pass
```

And here the traceback:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 920, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File ".../server/edition.py", line 62, in run
    self.sock.send(outs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 678, in send
    v = self._sslobj.write(data)
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1638)
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL/TLS is a layer on top of TCP. But, while TCP is done in the kernel SSL/TLS is done in user space. There are two problems because of this:

The first problem is that the user space and thus the SSL state is duplicated when doing the fork inside `subprocess.Popen`. But any actions on this socket in the parent or the child will not be synchronized with the state in the other process so if both processes actively deal with the socket (which includes closing it) it will cause a failure in the SSL state which results in an error in the connection.

Even if only the child process deals with the problem the exec after the fork (as done in `subprocess.Popen`) will make only the kernel file descriptor available to the process (`rvim` in your case`) but not the user space SSL layer, since this user space was inside the Python process only. This way the subprocess will communicate using a plain TCP socket whereas the server expects SSL. This will also cause a connection error and ultimately connection close. See also [Python3 CGI HTTPS server fails on Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303343/python3-cgi-https-server-fails-on-unix).

The only way I could think of is to keep the SSL socket in the parent only and use separate pipes (or socketpair) to communicate with the subprocess. All data received from the server in the parent (using SSL) should be forwarded as plain  to the subprocess and all data from the subprocess should be send with SSL to the server inside the parent.